# The column 'newscatid' was specified multiple times for 'DerivedTableName'

Tags: c#, sql

The function below gives me a surrender Please give me a thanks.

> The column 'newscatid' was specified multiple times for'DerivedTableName'.
>
> The multipart identifier "NEWSCAT20p.sabcat" could not be bound.
>
> The multi-part identifier "NEWS20p.newscatid" could not be bound.
>
> The multi-part identifier "NEWSCAT20p.newscatid" could not be bound.

```
    if (HiddenField1.Value == "0")
    {
        //تابع پیچینگ ساخته شده توسط خودم
        Paging.Paging pg = new Paging.Paging();
        pg.ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conectapp"].ToString();
        pg.TopView = rowcontRep = 6;

        string strQ = Request.QueryString["Page"];
        if (strQ != null)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            // شرط،کلید جدول،فیلدها،نام جدول
            ds = pg.GetData(int.Parse(strQ), "NEWS20p,NEWSCAT20p", "*", "newsid", "and NEWSCAT20p.sabcat=" + HiddenField1.Value + "  and NEWS20p.newscatid=NEWSCAT20p.newscatid ");//اگر شرط دارداول رشته //and// میخواهد
            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                //کد
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {                           
                        persianDate prsDate2 = new persianDate(Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[3].Rows[i].ToString()));
                        Literal1.Text += "<div class='col-lg-4 col-md-6'><div class='single-blog-post'><div class='blog-image'><a href='/post/" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ToString() + "/" + Seo.GenerateSlug(ds.Tables[1].Rows[i].ToString()) + "'><img width='100%' height='270px' src='" + ds.Tables[8].Rows[i].ToString() + "' alt='image'></a>";
                        Literal1.Text += "<div class='date'><i data-feather='calendar'></i> " + prsDate2.simpleDate() + "  " + prsDate2.Time3() + "</div></div><div class='blog-post-content'><h3><a href='/post/" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ToString() + "/" + Seo.GenerateSlug(ds.Tables[1].Rows[i].ToString()) + "'>" + ds.Tables[1].Rows[i].ToString() + "</a></h3><span>توسط <a href='#'>" + ds.Tables[6].Rows[i].ToString() + "</a></span><p>" + ds.Tables[4].Rows[i].ToString() + "</p><a href='/post/" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ToString() + "/" + Seo.GenerateSlug(ds.Tables[1].Rows[i].ToString()) + "' class='read-more-btn'>بیشتر بخوانید <i data-feather='arrow-left'></i> </a></div></div></div>";
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Literal1.Visible = false;
                    }

                    //پایان کد
                }
            } litPage.Text = pg.GetDataPaging("NEWS20p,NEWSCAT20p", int.Parse(strQ), Request.QueryString.ToString(), "newsid", "where NEWSCAT20p.sabcat=" + HiddenField1.Value + "  and NEWS20p.newscatid=NEWSCAT20p.newscatid ");//اگر شرط دارد اول رشته //WHERE// میخواهد
        }
        else
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = pg.GetData(1, "NEWS20p,NEWSCAT20p", "*", "newsid", "and NEWSCAT20p.sabcat=" + HiddenField1.Value + "  and NEWS20p.newscatid=NEWSCAT20p.newscatid ");//اگر شرط دارد اول رشته// and// میخواهد
            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                //کد
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        persianDate prsDate2 = new persianDate(Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[3].Rows[i].ToString()));
                        Literal1.Text += "<div class='col-lg-4 col-md-6'><div class='single-blog-post'><div class='blog-image'><a href='/post/" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ToString() + "/" + Seo.GenerateSlug(ds.Tables[1].Rows[i].ToString()) + "'><img width='100%' height='270px' src='" + ds.Tables[8].Rows[i].ToString() + "' alt='image'></a>";
                        Literal1.Text += "<div class='date'><i data-feather='calendar'></i> " + prsDate2.simpleDate() + "  " + prsDate2.Time3() + "</div></div><div class='blog-post-content'><h3><a href='/post/" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ToString() + "/" + Seo.GenerateSlug(ds.Tables[1].Rows[i].ToString()) + "'>" + ds.Tables[1].Rows[i].ToString() + "</a></h3><span>توسط <a href='#'>" + ds.Tables[6].Rows[i].ToString() + "</a></span><p>" + ds.Tables[4].Rows[i].ToString() + "</p><a href='/post/" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ToString() + "/" + Seo.GenerateSlug(ds.Tables[1].Rows[i].ToString()) + "' class='read-more-btn'>بیشتر بخوانید <i data-feather='arrow-left'></i> </a></div></div></div>";
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Literal1.Visible = false;
                    }

                    //پایان کد
                }
            }
            litPage.Text = pg.GetDataPaging("NEWS20p,NEWSCAT20p", 1, Request.QueryString.ToString(), "newsid", "where NEWSCAT20p.sabcat=" + HiddenField1.Value + "  and NEWS20p.newscatid=NEWSCAT20p.newscatid ");// اگر شرط دارد اول رشته// WHERE// میخواهد
        }
        // تابع پیجینگ پایان
        Label1.Text = HiddenField2.Value.Replace("-"," ");
    }
enter code here
```

namespace Paging
{

```
public class Paging
{
    private int inttop;
    public int conterC;
    public int TopView
    {
        set
        {
            inttop = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return inttop;
        }
    }
    private string strConStr;
    public string ConnectionString
    {
        set
        {
            strConStr = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return strConStr;
        }
    }
    private string GetQstring(string q)
    {
        string strP;
        strP = q;
        string[] strSp;
        strSp = strP.Split('&');
        strP = "";
        string stro;
        foreach (string ss in strSp)
        {
            stro = ss;
            if (ss.Length > 3)
            {
                if (ss.Substring(0, 4).ToLower() == "page")
                {
                    stro = "";
                }
            }

            if (stro != "")
            {
                strP += stro + "&";
            }
        }
        return strP;
    }
    private int SetPageNumber(int intPageNumber)
    {
        int intNum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= intPageNumber - 1; i++)
        {
            intNum += inttop;
        }
        intNum += 1;
        return intNum;
    }
    private int GetRecordNumberPost(string strTableName,string keytable,string shart)
    {
        string strConnection = strConStr;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
        string strCmd = "select count(" + keytable + ")as Num from " + strTableName + " "+ shart +"";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd, con);
        SqlDataReader dd;
        int intNum = 0;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            dd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dd.Read();
            intNum = int.Parse(dd["Num"].ToString());
            conterC = intNum;
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            intNum = 0;
            con.Close();
        }
        return intNum;
    }
    public DataSet GetData(int intPage, string strTableName, string strFild, string keytable,string shart)
    {
        intPage = SetPageNumber(intPage);
        string strConnection = strConStr;
        string strCmd = @"SELECT TOP(" + TopView.ToString() + ") " + strFild + " FROM (SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY " + keytable + " DESC) as  RowNum FROM " +  strTableName + ") as DerivedTableName WHERE RowNum >= @PageIndex "+shart+"";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageIndex", intPage.ToString());

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
      //  try
      //  {
            con.Open();
            da.Fill(ds, strTableName);
            con.Close();
      //  }
      //  catch
      //  {
           con.Close();
      //  }
        return ds;
    }
    public string GetDataPaging(string strTableName, int intPage, string strQ, string keytable, string shart)
    {
        int i = GetRecordNumberPost(strTableName, keytable,shart);
        string strP = "";
        int Num = (int)i / inttop;
        if (Num * inttop < i)
        {
            Num++;
        }

        int intBou = 1;
        if (intPage > 5)
        {
            intBou = (intPage - 5) + 1;
        }
        if (Num - intPage < 5)
        {
            int intbb = 9;
            intBou = Num - intbb;
            while (intBou < 1)
            {
                if (intBou < 1)
                {
                    intbb -= 1;
                    intBou = Num - intbb;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        int intb = intPage;
        if (intb > 1)
        {
            strP += "<a href='?" + GetQstring(strQ) + "Page=1' class='pageN'><<</a>  ";
        }
        for (int k = intBou; k <= (intBou + 9); k++)
        {
            if (k > Num)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (k == intPage)
            {
                strP += "<a class='pageL1'> " + k.ToString() + "</a>  ";
            }
            else
            {
                strP += "<a href='?" + GetQstring(strQ) + "Page=" + k.ToString() + "' class='pageN'>" + k.ToString() + "</a>  ";
            }
        }
        if (intb < Num)
        {
            strP += "<a href='?" + GetQstring(strQ) + "Page=" + Num + "' class='pageN'>>></a>  ";
        }

        strP += " -- "+ "تعداد کل رکوردها = " + conterC;
        return strP;

    }
}
```

}

The problem is here

> @"SELECT TOP(5) * FROM (SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY newsid  DESC) as  RowNum FROM NEWS20p,NEWSCAT20p) as NEWS20p,NEWSCAT20p WHERE RowNum >= @PageIndex and NEWSCAT20p.sabcat=" + HiddenField1.Value + "  and NEWS20p.newscatid=NEWSCAT20p.newscatid "

Comment: you use `"*"` this means the database returns all columns of all tables used in the statement. you called `"*", "newsid"` => this means you get all colums and additionally "newsid". so you get this column twice.